# passing multiple arguments that are file names from multiple txt files to a c program ran in linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, arguments

I have a project that requires converting a big list of .bin files to an equivalent big list of .csv files. The converter script is already written in c by a company called agilent, the catch 22 is the script only converts one .bin file at a time. but once converted, it will be in the correct format for my project

The c program (called agilent_bin_reader.c) works fine when I type the arguments manually, but when the arguments come from a .txt file then the file opener fails to open the file. I want to automate the process to run the c program thousands of time so I created a script.sh that repeats the process until EOF of either one of the txt files.

Manually entered Example) `linux_shell$ ./agilent_bin_reader des_trace1.bin trace1.csv`

Saves the binary information from des_trace1.bin into trace1.csv perfectly.

My problem is when I run this c program using my script.sh I get the error that the file basically failed to open. Its a problem with this part of the c code:

```
inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
if (inputFile)
```

because the if never evaluates to true. the else that follows basically kicks me out of the code.

Heres my script.sh that Ive created:

```
while 
  IFS= read -r a1 <&3 &&
  IFS= read -r a2 <&4
do
  ./agilent_bin_reader "$a1" "$a2" 3<&- 4<&-
done 3< names1.txt 4< names2.txt
```

As one can see, the arguments here are *names1.txt* and *names2.txt* as they pass into argv[1] and argv[2] respectively. But even though the arguments are perfectly set up, **its almost like the fopen thinks it should be looking in the names1.txt file for the .bin file but really the .bin files are sitting in the same folder as agilent_bin_reader.c, names1.txt, and names2.txt.** There shouldnt be any issues with directories unless my script.sh makes the *fopen* only look at the .txt file that the argv[] goes into.

I want the code to do this basically:

```
linux_shell$ ./agilent_bin_reader names1.txt(1st line) names2.txt(1st line)
linux_shell$ ./agilent_bin_reader names1.txt(2nd line) names2.txt(2nd line)
linux_shell$ ./agilent_bin_reader names1.txt(3rd line) names2.txt(3rd line)
....
....
linux_shell$ ./agilent_bin_reader names1.txt(81,569th line) names2.txt(81,569th line)
*EOF of both .txt files, iteration complete
```

My names1.txt file looks like:

```
des_trace1.bin
des_trace2.bin
des_trace3.bin
...
des_trace81569.bin
```

My names2.txt file looks like:

```
trace1.csv
trace2.csv
trace3.csv
...
trace81569.csv
```

Here is the converter code supplied to me (Is found at http://www.dpacontest.org/agilent_bin_reader.c) {I named this program agilent_bin_reader.c just like the company who created it did}

Comment: I checked the script provided and it works well. Have you checked that the file exists? Can you show us the exact error you get?

Comment: Unable to open wave_DES_HW_2007-09-26_18-20-42__k=6b64796b64796b64_m=0000000000000000_c=e37843ccfa2e6d78.bin

Comment: Its odd though, because when I take that name and copy it into the terminal manually it works perfectly

Comment: And when you do an `ls "wave_DES_HW_2007-09-26_18-20-42__k=6b64796b64796b64_m=0000000000000000_c=e37843ccfa2e6d78.bin"`, the file appears?

Comment: Check also that you have read permission on the file. But it is weird, it should work.

Comment: 'wave_DES_HW_2007-09-26_18-20-42__k=6b64796b64796b64_m=0000000000000000_c=e37843ccfa2e6d78.bin' , yes it shows up perfectly.. I will try the permissions on the txt files. Very good catch.

Comment: One minor improvement: You should be able to use `IFS= read -r -u 3 a1 && IFS= read -r -u 4 a2` instead of that redirection.

Comment: Yes the file is readable. Just checked by 'ls -lg names1.txt' All checks out. I also know this is reading properly because I place code in the c program to print off the argv[1] and argv[2] values.       printf("%s\n", argv[1]);         printf("%s\n", argv[2]);  and they came back as the file names stored in the .txt files

Comment: Do those files have Windows style CRLF line endings instead of Unix style LF? Use `file names[12].txt` to see. Your program might be trying to open `des_trace1.bin\r`.

Comment: Shawn could you please elaborate? Im pretty novice at this.. Apologize in advance. Do you mean that I should rename my names1.txt to names1[12].txt? And what is \r?

Comment: No, that's the filename glob to match both files. `file names1.txt names2.txt` works too, or `file names*.txt`, etc. etc. etc. `\r` is a carriage return just like `\n` is a linefeed in C strings (And many other languages).

Comment: Okay I typed in 'file names1.txt names2.txt' and the return was:::                      
names1.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
names2.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: So Shawn, yes it looks like the files use CRLF line terminators. Is this causing me troubles?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was something like that. Like I said, that means your C program is trying to open files like `des_trace1.bin\r`, `trace1.csv\r`, etc. instead of the actual filenames `des_trace1.bin`, `trace1.csv`, etc. Running those two names files through `dos2unix` is the easiest way to fix them.

Comment: Wow, youre a rockstar/lifesaver all-in-one. I wouldnt have found it in a million years. A little help from sudo apt=install dos2unix and away I went. Works perfectly. Tie a bow on it.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn in the comments section found that my issue was my txt files had hidden characters in them.. Ran dos2unix and my problem instantly went away. See this website for a detailed explanation: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dos2unix-removing-hidden-windows-characters-from-files/

Here are the commands I ran:

```
linux_shell$ sudo apt install dos2unix
linux_shell$ dos2unix names1.txt
linux_shell$ dos2unix names2.txt
```